# how to save the pic that lifelines module plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
In [3]: type(kmf) 
Out[3]: lifelines.estimation.KaplanMeierFitter
In [2]: kmf.plot()
Out[2]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x533b970>
```

kmf haven't the function to save the figure，when I run 'kmf.plot()',the pic omly will show in the shell, I need kmf could be like pyplot.savefig, then I can save the figure to disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `lifelines` module uses `matplotlib` for plotting. The `plot` method returns an `AxesSubplot` instance for the plot. This can be used to gain access to the figure containing the subplot and then the `savefig` method can be used:

```
ax = kmf.plot()
ax.get_figure().savefig("myfigure.png")
```